# Options other than Applet

Tags: java, gwt, applet, javafx

I am using the XMPP to build the Chat Application.
For building chat client I am using the Applet to communicate with the XMPP Server using their APIs in Applet.

So my question is: Is there anything other than Applet that I can use to communicate with Server and also with use of the XMPP Client API (i.e. options other than applet)?

I looking into GWT and JavaFX, will those two be helpful in this context?

Comment: you can use any thing including servelets

Comment: But those are on server side things , i want something to on client side

Comment: +1 for choosing to avoid applets, they can add extra deployment & maintenance problems that do not affect an app. launched outside the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java-WebStart or Flex or just write a small webpage using servlets.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely check out [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It can launch a `JFrame` from a link, and offers many deployment advantages.

Comment: Yes to Swing/AWT.  JWS can launch SWT as well. JWS can launch any 'rich client' desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a browser-based client then use Flash. There are several XMPP [browser clients](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/) and [libraries](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/) available.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of JavaScript libraries listed on the [XMPP website](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/). So no need to rely on browser plug-ins, just do a native web application.

You can easily use GWT for your web application. A quick search on Google revealed some GWT specific third party libraries or XMPP ([Emite](https://code.google.com/p/emite/), [gwt-strophe](https://launchpad.net/gwt-strophe)) and even a samples app ([Emite Chat](http://emite.ourproject.org/)).